# MongoDb regexMatch inconsistent behavior

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The query works if I assign it as a normal string

```
const searchField = "$$data.product";
```

But If I try to use concatenation and add a variable name
`const searchField = "$$data." + key;`
then it fails with the error:

MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation:: caused by:: $regexMatch needs 'input' to be of type string

I have tried using template format but it also does not work `$$data.${key}`

Comment: What is the value of `key`? What's the surrounding code that uses `searchField`?

Comment: thank you for your time but my issue was a stupid mistake by me 
I was adding an array field to the regex when it only accepts string fields. So I remove the string field and now it works normally